# How to make unequal GridLayout rows

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

I am wanting to make each cell in a row a different length..
Here is a picture to help.

[image]

So the Policy cell and the text to the right is fine. However, Section 1 and Section 2 I want to be 50/50.. Not 20/80 or whatever it is now. I have started using the WindowsBuilder tool instead of doing this by hand. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Is this SWT or Swing - both have (different) GridLayouts? This can certainly be done using multiple levels of GridLayout in SWT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To lay out controls in the requested manner with a GridLayout in SWT you will have to *group* the controls of each row into a composite of their own like so:

```
shell.setLayout( new RowLayout( SWT.VERTICAL ) );
Composite composite1 = new Composite( shell, SWT.NONE );
composite1.setLayout( new GridLayout( 2, false ) );
createLabel( composite1, "2020" );
createLabel( composite1, "808080808080" );

Composite composite2 = new Composite( shell, SWT.NONE );
composite2.setLayout( new GridLayout( 2, false ) );
createLabel( composite2, "50505050" );
createLabel( composite2, "50505050" );

private static Label createLabel( Composite parent, String text ) {
  Label label = new Label( parent, SWT.NONE );
  label.setText( text );
  return label;
}
```

[image]

However, to me a `FormLayout` seems more suitable to solve the given problem:

```
shell.setLayout( new FormLayout() );
FormData leftFormData = new FormData();
leftFormData.top = new FormAttachment( 0 );
leftFormData.left = new FormAttachment( 0 );
leftFormData.right = new FormAttachment( 20 );
Label leftLabel = createLabel( shell, "2020", leftFormData );
FormData rightFormData = new FormData();
rightFormData.top = new FormAttachment( 0 );
rightFormData.left = new FormAttachment( leftLabel );
rightFormData.right = new FormAttachment( 100 );
createLabel( shell, "808080808080", rightFormData );

private static Label createLabel( Composite parent, String text, Object layoutData ) {
  Label label = new Label( parent, SWT.NONE );
  label.setText( text );
  label.setLayoutData( layoutData );
  return label;
}
```

If you find the formData and formAttachment code too verbose, you may have a look at [Slim Down SWT FormLayout Usage](http://www.codeaffine.com/2014/03/31/slim-down-swt-formlayout-usage/)

And for an in-depth discussion of SWT layouts I recommend the [Understanding Layouts in SWT](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html) article.

Comment: Thank you! I actually like using the grid layout inside the row layout. Now I just need the RowData to span the size of the screen.

Comment: Be aware that using the `GridLayout` _wastes_ an extra `Composite` per row and might lead to performacne issues when there are many rows. To span the size of the parent, you can use a `FillLayout` or a single-row `GridLayout` with `GridData`s like `new GridData( SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, true, false )`. to take all the horizontal space.

Comment: My issue is really here: composite.setLayoutData(new RowData(622, 34)); I really want RowData to span the screen and not be a set size.

Comment: No sure what you mean by _screen_. If you want a control to span its entire parent, a RowLayout is the wrong choice. See my above comment that suggests `FillLayout` or `GridLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Missed that you are using `SWT` `GridLayout` instead of the `Swing` one. My solution works with `Swing` so keep that in mind.

You may want to use the `GridBagLayout`. It's more complicated than the `GridLayout` but offers greater flexibility

See some documentation on how to use it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

Comment: Is this not possible with the normal GridLayout?

Comment: @ChrisBolton If you look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471502/how-can-i-make-my-columns-different-sizes-using-gridlayout-in-swing) you can see in the answer it is possible with a combination of `FlowLayout` and `GridLayout` but that makes it very tedious and very complicated. With `GridBagLayout` it's still tedious but not as much. I Strongly suggest using `GridBagLayout` because its the most flexible option. And once you understand it it becomes less tedious. **tl;dr: No.**

Comment: GridBagLayout is AWT/Swing, the question is about SWT.

Comment: @greg-449 Missed that part

Comment: Yeah, I believe the best solution is to use FlowLayout with GridLayout. Then, I can stick with SWT.